# On selection of li cursor goes down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented autosuggestion on word in div that will appear at exact cursor place after pressing `up` and `down` arrow word is selected but cursor also goes down.

```css
#cont_div, #cont_text, #demo
{
    resize: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 19px;
    -webkit-line-height: 19px;
    -moz-line-height: 19px;
    -o-line-height: 19px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #CCC !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
    color: #262626;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 500px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 40px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #CCC !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #CCC !important;
}
li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">
    <ul style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px;">
        <li><a>a</a></li>
        <li><a>b</a></li>
        <li><a>c</a></li>
        <li><a>a</a></li>
        <li><a>b</a></li>
        <li><a>c</a></li>
        <li><a>a</a></li>
        <li><a>b</a></li>
        <li><a>c</a></li>
        <li><a>a</a></li>
        <li><a>b</a></li>
        <li><a>c</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want cursor on that position only.., any suggestion?

Comment: So what JS/Jquery are you using? And if you could make a Fiddle out of it, it would be easier to test.

Comment: I feel like there should be some JavaScript here, just hardcode some dummy data to give us an idea of the functionality.

Comment: run the snippet..u will get an idea what is exactly problem here @StefanNeuenschwander